# How do I convert a page's title to lower case?

Tags: pages

On my test case, the page' title is "Privacy".  The straightforward approach

```
strtolower(the_title())
```

also returns "Privacy" -- still with a capital P.  I also tried

```
mb_strtolower(the_title())
```

and

```
mb_strtolower(the_title(), 'utf8')
```

with similar results.

Not sure if it matters, but my wp-config.php has

```
define('WPLANG', '');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Comment: `thetitle()` is not a WordPress function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## lowercasing the title

If I'm understanding you correctly, you should be doing:

```
strtolower(get_the_title());
```

or

```
print strtolower(get_the_title());
```

if you want to display it. Below is an explanation as to why.

## the_title() vs. get_the_title()

The function `the_title()` [prints the current post's title unless you pass `false` as its third argument](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L43). Unless you call it like:

```
$title = the_title('', '', false);
```

The title will be printed, and the `$title` variable won't contain anything. This matters because calling `strtolower()` on an empty variable doesn't do very much.

You [want to use `get_the_title()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) in most cases where you're looking to fill a variable with the content posts title.

Note, however, that if you're not currently in a loop, you'll need to pass a post ID to `get_the_title()`. In almost all cases when on a single post or page you can do this by using:

```
get_the_title($post->ID);
```

as the `$post` variable should be in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks, I was in fact confused betweet the_title() and get_the_title()

Answer (score 6):

I think the best method for this is by using CSS (text-transform: lowercase).

But if you want to use PHP, WP for this you can use: `<h1><?php echo strtolower( get_the_title() ); ?></h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great plugin for doing this.  It's on my website, WordPress.org, Github and others.  It's 100% free, with no membership versions.  Please feel free to download it.  This does it on the data level, which allows you to change it later, or do it on some and not others. It's a good option, and as I said.  Works Great!

My Site:

https://properprogramming.com/tools/wp-change-titles-case/

Wordpress:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-titles-case/