# How to prevent uppercasing of menu titles

Tags: categories, menus

My category names are being converted to uppercase when I use them as menu items.

Here's how I created a category:

[image]

And here's how it is displayed:

[image]

Is the theme doing this or is it WordPress itself?  In either case, how can I prevent this?

Comment: **Duplicate:** [see](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/how-do-i-convert-a-pages-title-to-lower-case) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6243312) for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the theme doing. Most of the time the text is transformed by css.

Comment: Yes, you are right, just figured it out myself, it's the style.css file in action. Thanks.